# JavaScript object property is undefined when is shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the Knockout.js' binding syntax for currentFolder.
I have the code:

```
alert(self.currentFolder().folderName + self.currentFolder());
```

now, for the self.currentFolder() alerts:

```
{
"folderSize": "105.73MB",
"folderName": "root",
"subFolders": [
    {
        "folderSize": "0Byte",
        "folderName": "Reacl child of Root",
        "subFolders": [],
        "filesInFolder": []
    }
],
"filesInFolder": [
    {
        "fileType": "mp4",
        "checkSum": "4e3e31d46b4ad120af47c0836340df4d",
        "fileSize": "105.73MB",
        "fileName": "fileName.mp4",
        "date": "14-11-2013 16:52:53",
        "resourceLink": "eyJpdiI6IllaSWI5SGxTajg0dVBGUVdiNERGN3JJbllWS29UZStxclhcL1JwUDNjbkJZPSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNitNSitcL1wvVVNpT2ExdUJRWG9xazZPTFduNm90bW5BUTE2OUFnOGZ1cDBBMmJMazNcL1wvSEREM3hOczR2anNHOGNNZDFvUUc3RkxQWlhHdDVcLzJkQlVcL3c9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImUzYzIwMTM0NWFhNzBkZDY2ZjhkMmNkYjcyZThlZDJmZDIxYzYzZTBjYmI5MjQxYjgzOWY0ZmUxNDM4MWQ2YjAifQ=="
    }
]
}
```

but I have no idea why for self.currentFolder().folderName outputs undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use alert, use `console.log` or `debugger`.

Answer (score 0):

If `folderName` is an observable, then you need to call it as a function, like with any other observable types. This should work for you.

```
self.currentFolder().folderName()
```